# Using millis() to toggle an LED every 500 milliseconds

Tags: arduino-nano

I thought the code below would toggle an LED every 500 milliseconds. But it does not work. I'm not able to catch the mistake, which must be very silly.

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long cnt=millis();
  if(!(cnt % 500)) {
    PORTD^= (1<<PD3);
  }
}
```

Anyhow the code below works. But why not the previous code?

```
void loop() {
  static unsigned long prev=0;
  // Note: First time case is not handled. As soon as we want to toggle,
  // we must store millis() in prev. In this case this happens after reset and may not be an issue.
  unsigned long current = millis();
  if((unsigned long)(current - prev) >= 500) {
    PORTD^= (1<<PD3);
    prev = current;
  }
}
```

Comment: A further problem with the first example, not yet mentioned, is that the if() logic is reversed. `if( !(cnt % 500) )` is equivalent to `if( (cnt % 500) != 0 )`, which is true for 499 values and false for only one. The "!" creates the opposite effect to what was wanted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> `if (!(millis() % 500)) ...`

There are two issues with this. The first, and most obvious, is that the
condition will be true for a full millisecond. During that millisecond
you will be toggling the LED on and off very fast. Whether you end up
doing an odd or even number of toggles is anyone's guess.

The second and less obvious problem is that `millis()` skips some
values. Roughly one integer every 42 is skipped over. This is because
the `millis()` counter is incremented once every 1024 µs, getting
24 µs late on each increment. Once all those delays add up to a
full millisecond, `millis()` catches up by incrementing the counter by
two milliseconds instead of one. This is why you should never condition
something on `millis()` having one specific value.

The almost correct solution to this problem is shown in Juraj's answer:

> `if (millis() > next) ...`

This is not quite correct because it fails each time `millis()` rolls
over back to zero. The correct solution is

```c++
static unsigned long last;
if (millis() - last >= 500) {
    last += 500;
    ...
}
```

Because the subtraction follows the rules of modular arithmetic, this is
guaranteed to work across the rollover events.

Comment: the overrun is after 49 days. if the sketch has restart scheduled every day the the subtraction is unnecessary

Comment: @Juraj: Scheduling restarts is a very contrived way of avoiding the rollover “issue”, which is a non-issue to start with if you do the arithmetic properly.

Comment: if it has scheduled restart for other reasons

Comment: @Juraj Then when those restarts stop... suddenly you have an unexpected, bizarre situation.

Comment: You're in good company with scheduled reboots! https://www.theguardian.com/business/2015/may/01/us-aviation-authority-boeing-787-dreamliner-bug-could-cause-loss-of-control And if you forget it's just a trivial *complete electric shutdown of Boeing’s 787 and [potential] “loss of control” of the aircraft.*

Comment: And don't forget, this is the same crowd that asks people to put timers on their routers so they reboot once a month.

Comment: initialize variable last

Comment: @Juraj: It's `static`, therefore it's initialized by the rules of the language. You can add `= 0` if you don't trust the language, or `= -500` if you want the first iteration to start right away, or even `= millis() - 500` if your `setup()` takes an insanely long time.

Answer (score 4):

Your timing doesn't work, because it has a low probability to read a millisecond that is an exact multiple of 500.

Do it this way:

```
  static unsigned long next = millis();
  if (millis() - next > 500) {
    next += 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void loop() {
  unsigned long cnt=millis();
  if(!(cnt % 500)) {
    PORTD^= (1<<PD3);
  }
}
```

At every iteration, `cnt` is set with the number of milliseconds elapsed **since you turned on the Arduino...** So this is not gonna work. At all. What you need is two variables. One that holds the last `millis()` count when you blinked the LED, and for the current `millis()` count:

```
unsigned long lastCount;
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  lastCount=millis();
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long cnt=millis();
  if((cnt-lastCount)>499) {
    PORTD^= (1<<PD3);
    lastCount=cnt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this

```
if((millis()/500)%2==0)) 
{
    PORTD |= (1<<PD3);
}
else
{
    PORTD &= ~(1<<PD3);
}
```

It first divides millis by 500ms. So you get the number of 500ms chucks (since the Arduino started). Then you check to see if this number is even. If so, turn the led pin on. Else turn the led pin off.

Comment: Division is a computationally expensive operation on most embedded micros.  You should avoid it if possible.